# tcpdump capture traffics on kaa server

Tags: kaa

I have a device with kaa C sdk that is connected with a kaa server.  The devices and kaa server communications work well, I could see the data of the device was uploaded regularly to mongo DB on the kaa server. However, when tried to use tcpdump to capture the traffic on the server, I could not get any packets from the device.

So wondering what I missed. Anything special needs be taken cared to capture networking packets of kaa devices?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: which transport protocol do you use on kaa ? did you start capturing on right interface ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should normally see packets from an enpoint on the Kaa server. You would normally not get the packets data (due to encoding and optional encryption), but the fact of packets delivery should be visible.

Try checking the filtering you are using:

- check the network interface the tcpdump listens on
- check the filter settings (e.g. enpoint IP address on the Kaa server side may be different to what it is locally configured)